# How get values in fields [NotMapped] using ajax post (ASP NET MVC 4)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How get values in fields [NotMapped] attributes using ajax post (ASP NET MVC 4)?

```
 $('#btnSalvarParcela').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CadastroLancamentoParcelar", "LancamentoReceitaDespesa")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#LancamentoForm").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        context: this,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partialLancamentoReceitaDespesa").html(result);
            mudarComboTipoLancamento();
        }
    });
});
```

("#LancamentoForm").serialize() - the field [notmapped] is going to controller as null, is to retrieve these values​​?

Comment: you can probably get all the values using the Request.QueryString property off the context.

Comment: what is `("#LancamentoForm")`? is the value of a textbox? hidden field? because it looks like  you are not passing this correctly

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form["YourInput"]; will get it if it was posted. I'd guess it's most likely not part of the form, or there's a typo or something. (However, I am not familiar with [NotMapped])